# Unable to download text file with download attribute

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to download a file with the following snippet. File is text file.

```
var element = document.createElement('a');
element.setAttribute('href', URL);
element.setAttribute('download', filename);
element.style.display = 'none';
document.body.appendChild(element);
element.click();
document.body.removeChild(element);
```

I am testing it in chrome. It opens a file in browser rather then to download it.

Comment: I think href should be the path to the file and download needs to be `true` or `false`

Comment: @Sv443 — The `href` **is** the URL to the file and you are completely wrong about the value of the `download` attribute.

Comment: @Quentin I meant that it can be set to true or false in the script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a):

> This attribute only works for same-origin URLs.

Odds are that you are linking to a URL on a different origin.

You can't override that with the `download` attribute.

Set a `Content-Disposition` HTTP response header instead.

Comment: Yes origin is different. Then why zip files are being downloaded with same piece of code ?

Comment: @AfnanAhmad — Browsers download zip files by default. They can't render them inline. The `download` attribute still does nothing.

Comment: Then what would be the work around for it if I don't have access to the server ?

Comment: @AfnanAhmad — Fetch the data with Ajax (requires the server you don't have access to to grant permission with CORS) and generate a download with inline data or set the `URL` to point to your own server and have it proxy the data for you (adding whatever headers you like)

Comment: If its the only solution to add Content-Disposition http response header, then would you please guide how to do this in c# ? Any refrences please.

Answer (score -1):

I set a binary mime type because  `text/plain` is known by the browsers and just opened instead of showing the download window. Try this code

```js
var text = "Test Line1\n Line2 \n Line3";

var fileBlob = new Blob([text], {type: "application/octet-binary"});

var link = document.createElement("a");
link.setAttribute("href", URL.createObjectURL(fileBlob));
link.setAttribute("download", "HelloWorld.txt");
link.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Click here to download file"));
document.body.appendChild(link);
```

Comment: The question is about downloading from a URL not creating a file using data in a string.

Comment: @Quentin, please read the question: 'It opens a file in browser rather then to download it.'

Comment: @PoulBak — That means that the content of the file is displayed in the browser window instead of being saved to a file in the Downloads directory. It doesn't mean that the *source* of the file is the browser (the source is the URL on the third party server).